# my regex is not working for maximum limit

Tags: php, regex

Hello i have a regex which accepts mostly every character including specials.And i have set 
it to accept minimum 8 and maximum 30 characters. 
Everything is right for minimum but it's not working for maximum.

If string is more than 30 or any length. The result is true.

The pattern is here:

```
 $pattern = '/[A-Za-z0-9' . preg_quote( '.%^&()$#@!/-+/', '/') . ']{8,30}/';
```

The whole testing code is:

```
 $pattern = '/^[A-Za-z0-9' . preg_quote( '.%^&()$#@!/-+/', '/') . ']{8,30}$/';

 if(preg_match($pattern, $pass))
   {
     echo '<br>true';
   }
 else
   {
 echo '<br>false';
    }


?>
```

Comment: The only characters you need to escape in a character set are `]`, `-` (when not first or last), `^` (when first), and a backslash.

Answer (score 3):

This will match any string up to 30 characters within the string. You need to include the start and end of the string:

```
$pattern = '/^[A-Za-z0-9' . preg_quote( '.%^&()$#@!/-+/', '/') . ']{8,30}$/';
```

Comment: thanks. it's working.I can't vote because i have not such reputation.

Comment: @vinaysingh: then accept the answer (click the checkmark on the left). that's the same as upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

The first `$pattern` expression in your question is missing the required: `^` and `$` *beginning and end of line assertions* - (but the example code snippet which follows uses them correctly.)

You also need to escape the dash/hyphen inside the character class - the hyphen defines a range of characters. (Note that the forward slash `/` is NOT the escape char!) Try this:

```php
$pattern = '/^[A-Za-z0-9.%^&()$#@!\-+\/]{8,30}$/';
```